# Use resources of high end servers to run lubuntu in low end hardware

Tags: server, virtualbox, lubuntu, remote

In our home there is one high end computer with lots of RAM and other low end old computer  running lubuntu , the lubuntu itself has become slow so we were thinking of making the lubuntu machine a complete thin client and that would use the server's lubuntu virtual machine. I feel that is possible but how?
I have oracle open box VM in the server can this VM be used as a remote VM on the thin client?

After a quick googling i found this [thinclient](http://www.thinstation.org/) which has an automated configurator for the thin client [here](http://tsomatic.agarwal-associates.com/index.php#). The least feature i want from this thin  system would be atleast a full blown libre office operation.

**Update:**

Using vncserver on the lubuntu worked great for me. But still I have to install lubuntu to run vncserver, is it possible to run vncserver without an OS? or lightest OS possible?, the lubuntu itelf is an unneeded additional overhead?

Comment: Don't cross-post, please. We've deleted your duplicate question on Super User.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways you can do this. The problem with most solutions is that they assume only one user is using the computer, so when you are connected no one else can connect.

X was supposed to do this very thing, as that is what it was designed for, but no one really used it remotely much because X used a lot of bandwidth, and during the peak of its popularity most people were using dial-up modems.

Eventually Ubuntu switched to away from X and lost the functionality to log into separate desktops remotely altogether. They replaced the X desktop with a window manager that uses Vino, a version of VNC, to remotely access your desktop. This means if you are connected no one else can use the computer, because Vino attaches to the root console and refuses to connect to any other user session.

Oracle VM has a built in remote desktop server that is independent of the operating system itself, but again the problem is that only one user can access it at a time.

The computing paradigm has moved away from multiple users using a computer at the same time because if five people could use the same computer at once you'd only buy one computer and Microsoft and hardware manufacturers would make 1/5th of the money.

The only way to achieve what you want to do with any reliability would be to install X and set up remote X sessions.

This article explains how to do so:

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Remote-X-Apps-9.html

Comment: thanks but I want the thin client to have fullblown functionality, using vncserver worked great for me. But still I have to install lubuntu to run vncserver, is it possible to run vncserver without an OS?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given the specs of your 'high end computer' nor whether you're interested in changing away from Oracle VM, so I'll throw out another idea in case it fits:

[VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org) (similar to VMWare) could let you re-purpose your high end computer as a host of a 'guest' virtual machine for your remote (thin) user.  Depending on its specs, the host might also support a (local) desktop user running on it, too.

VirtualBox supports the (thin) client connecting to the guest's (virtual) desktop using a remote desktop app like MSTSC.EXE.  Note that you're *not* taking over the actual host server's desktop - that remains separate.  Folks might be able to comment below as to whether a host computer is usable as a desktop with an active guest virtual machine.

Later on, if you wanted a second **remote** user, you could run up another virtual machine and connect to the server with a another (third) machine, also running a thin client remote desktop app.  Your 'high end computer' would need to be appropriately powerful to run all this though (1 local desktop plus 2 guest VMs).

PS: some folks see **VirtualBox** and **Oracle VM** as similar - the former is an application you install using apt-get (similar to VMWare Player) while the latter is installed onto the 'bare metal' of your server (more similar to VMWare ESXi).

Comment: The high end is  a 8 core Xeon with 16gb RAM, currently I am using vncserver like how you have suggested